# trying to make disclaimer view controller in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, view, controller

I want to display a view which contains the disclaimer for my app, only once. like, after you read it and press agree , never to show up again. when the app starts next time , jump straight to the next view in the storyboard (the login or whatever view). :( please explain the solution as detailed as possible because I'm new to iOS programming. thank you very much !

PS: I'm talking about ViewController for iOS in Xcode :)

Answer (score 1):

First time try to read from `NSUserDefaults` and check if a property is there, if not show the view controller and set a property in user defaults as,

In `didFinishLaunching` delegate method,

```
NSString *myString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"DidShowDisclaimer"]

if ([myString iEqualToString:@"YES"]) {
   //show the view controller and once they have accepted save this key
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"YES" forKey:@"DidShowDisclaimer"];
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; //next time when the app is launched it will never execute this if condition
}
```

So next time onwards, it would have been yes, and you never have to show again

Comment: @Daniel, If this helped, can you please accept it. There is a tick mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to store an NSUserDefault boolean to your app to know if your user accepted the user agreement or not.

So in terms of steps
1. app opens
2. check if boolean has been previously set
3. If not show them the agreement
4. If they agree then set the boolean to signify they've accepted and your check will always fail when the app is opened so you can skip the step.